# Условие с несколькими параметрами Laravel

Tags: laravel, запрос, model

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь получить данные, соответствующие условию

```
$products = App\Product::where([
    ['area', '>', $filters['minArea']],
    ['area', '<', $filters['maxArea']]
]);
```

Но, почему то возвращает пустой массив..Что я не так делаю?

Comment: а ты на 2 where пробовал разбивать ? `App\Product::where('area', '>', $filters['minArea'])->where('area', '<', $filters['maxArea'])->get()`, и кстати ты про get() забыл

Comment: Пробовал, возвращает пустой массив. И с get() тоже проверял..

Comment: Причем, вот такой запрос: $products = App\Product::where('area', '>', $filters['minArea'])->get();  отрабатывает нормально

Comment: тогда смотри в чем косяк может у тебя в maxArea не число, или число меньшее чем minArea или посмотри верный ли у тебя тип в таблице в плане что он int

Comment: Попробуйте whereBetween

Comment: Сейчас каким то чудом выполнился такой запрос:         $products = App\Product::where([
            ['area', '>', $filters['minArea']],
            ['area', '<', $filters['maxArea']]
        ])->get();
но, вывел всего 5 результатов, хотя если выполнить в базе данных sql запрос SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `area` > 142 AND `area` < 2500, выводит 10 (в БД выводит правильно). Все значения для сравнения одинаковые.

Comment: ```$products = App\Product::whereBetween('area', [$filters['minArea'], $filters['maxArea']])->get();```

Comment: Мой косяк) В БД полю area задал varchar) Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score -1):

```
$products = App\Product::whereBetween(
    'area', [ $filters['minArea'], $filters['maxArea'] ],
)->get();
```